# File upload using Multipart fails in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload a file in node js using multipart where I get Cannot POST error? I'm totally new to node js. So can you help me what I'm doing wrong 
My Code?
HTML

```
<form id   = "uploadForm"
     enctype   = "multipart/form-data"
     action    = "/api/uploadfile"
     method    = "post">
<input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

Server.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var multer  =   require('multer');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile("./index.html"); 
});

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('fileUpload');


app.post('/api/uploadfile',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});


app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

Error message as follows  :

> **Error uploading file**

Comment: It seems that you are requesting a route which is not registered in your node server. Can you cross check the URL requested from browser to upload file.

Comment: your code is completely fine, i even ran it in my machine. The file is getting uploaded. Except for that you missed the closing tag of  ```<form>```

Comment: @Nivesh i've closed the form on my code missed it here, no the code is not working for me am always getting an error message

Comment: @JitendraKhatri can yu explain me clearly am a rookie to node development

Comment: console log the error you are getting from multer

Comment: Open browser (chrome) console and go to Network tab and hover on the request of file uploading it shows you the full URL as tool-tip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i tried your code,its working here.The reason may be,

1)you missed out the closing of form tag

```
<html>
<form id       =  "uploadForm"
     enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
     action    =  "/api/uploadfile"
     method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="fileupload"  /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

2)make sure that you have a folder named -> uploads